# pd.Timedelta adds an extra day when calculating a difference between dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame `df`:

```
Actual                  Scheduled
2017-01-01 04:03:00.000 2017-01-01 04:25:00.000
2017-01-01 04:56:00.000 2017-01-01 04:55:00.000
2017-01-01 04:36:00.000 2017-01-01 05:05:00.000
2017-01-01 06:46:00.000 2017-01-01 06:55:00.000
2017-01-01 06:46:00.000 2017-01-01 07:00:00.000
```

I need to create an additional column `DIFF_MINUTES` that contains the difference (in minutes) between `Actual` and `Scheduled` (`Actual - Scheduled`).

This is how I tried to solve this task:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df["Actual"] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row["Actual"]),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), axis=1)
df["Scheduled"] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row["Scheduled"]),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"), axis=1)
df["DIFF_MINUTES"] = df.apply(lambda row: (pd.Timedelta(row["Actual"]-row["Scheduled"]).seconds)/60, axis=1)
```

However, I got wrong results for a negative difference cases (e.g. 04:03:00-04:25:00 should give 22 minutes instead of 1418 minutes):

```
Actual                      Scheduled              DIFF_MINUTES
2017-01-01 04:03:00         2017-01-01 04:25:00    1418.0
2017-01-01 04:56:00         2017-01-01 04:55:00    1.0
2017-01-01 04:36:00         2017-01-01 05:05:00    1411.0
2017-01-01 06:46:00         2017-01-01 06:55:00    1431.0
2017-01-01 06:46:00         2017-01-01 07:00:00    1426.0
```

How to fix it?

Expected result:

```
Actual                      Scheduled              DIFF_MINUTES
2017-01-01 04:03:00         2017-01-01 04:25:00    -22.0
2017-01-01 04:56:00         2017-01-01 04:55:00    1.0
2017-01-01 04:36:00         2017-01-01 05:05:00    -29
2017-01-01 06:46:00         2017-01-01 06:55:00    -9.0
2017-01-01 06:46:00         2017-01-01 07:00:00    -14.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) as (also check whether date is coming first or month in your columns):

```
df['Actual']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual'], dayfirst=True)
df['Scheduled']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Scheduled'], dayfirst=True)
df['DIFF_MINUTES'] = (df['Actual']-df['Scheduled']).dt.total_seconds()/60

print(df)
               Actual           Scheduled  DIFF_MINUTES
0 2017-01-01 04:03:00 2017-01-01 04:25:00         -22.0
1 2017-01-01 04:56:00 2017-01-01 04:55:00           1.0
2 2017-01-01 04:36:00 2017-01-01 05:05:00         -29.0
3 2017-01-01 06:46:00 2017-01-01 06:55:00          -9.0
4 2017-01-01 06:46:00 2017-01-01 07:00:00         -14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both column are *DateTime*, run just:

```
df['DIFF_MINUTES'] = (df.Actual - df.Scheduled).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

(a one-liner).

If you read this DataFrame e.g. from Excel or CSV file, add
*parse_dates=[0, 1]* parameter to have these columns converted into dates,
so that there will be no need to cast them by your code.

And if for some reason you have these column as **text**, then to
convert them run:

```
df.Actual = pd.to_datetime(df.Actual)
df.Scheduled = pd.to_datetime(df.Scheduled)
```

(another quicker solution than "plain Python" functions).

Comment: Can I specify column names instead of indices in the `parse_dates=[0, 1] `?

Comment: Yes. It is clearly stated in documentation of e.g. *read_csv*.